# Windows file explorer context menu option to open folder in visual studio code not showing

Tags: html, windows, visual-studio-code

Usually, on other PC's, when i right click on a folder and click on other options, i can choose to open the folder in visual studio code. Altough i can't seem to find it on my PC, even tho i use vsc very often.
It's not really a big deal, but it would be interesting knowing why it doesn't show.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnoGV.png)

I didn't try anything yet since i couldn't find an answer

Answer (score 0):

It might help to download the installer for vscode and install it again. It shouldn't overwrite any of your current configurations to do so, but you should be able to pick the option to [add VSCode to the context menu](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/9638156/48968771-6f715080-f005-11e8-8486-220cc183a830.png) during the installation process.

Answer (score 0):

Install it again using the installer and remember to check the options for "Add to context menu" this time around.